# Suppressing Strange output with Capybara/Selenium/RSpec

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm writing acceptance tests in Ruby using RSpec, Capybara, and Selenium. I have observed some messages in the output that I don't recognize, and that I haven't been able to find with Google searches.

Here is the output of one of my tests:

```
Authentication
  with an invalid email address
    gives an error message
  with an invalid password
[9344:5812:1011/235445:ERROR:navigation_entry_screenshot_manager.cc(141)] Invalid entry with unique id: 22
    gives an error message
  with a valid email and password
[9344:5812:1011/235450:ERROR:navigation_entry_screenshot_manager.cc(141)] Invalid entry with unique id: 33
    takes us to the correct page

3 examples, 0 failures
```

I have no idea what navigation_entry_screenshot_manager.cc is, and as long as it isn't causing a test to fail I don't really care. I just want to know if there is a way to stop it from showing up in the RSpec output.

Comment: Assuming you're using chrome with selenium it sounds like it's this bug - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=532290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly if it works for you, but here's how I suppress chrome warning messages in my specs:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, switches: ['--test-type'])
end
```